# Swift alamofire error

Tags: ios, alamofire

[image: Error from xcode]

So I'm trying to create a user on my database backend, everything is working on the app bar this segment on xcode, written in swift.

The backend can accept new users via this method but for some reason swift won't have it.

When I click register I get the error shown in the photo, code used

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, urlRequest, parameters: ["X-API-KEY": API_GENERAL_KEY,"username":userName.text!,"email": userMail.text!,"password":userPassword.text!,"profile_photo": self.imageName])
```

and the output is

```
<spotimusic.RadioStyleCollectionViewController: 0x7fe313d8fd00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
SDSD -  Optional("nathan@trojan-audio.com")
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Another error which shows in a segment is

[image: Error 2 from xcode]

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Comment: Try rewriting the line without the force unwrapping.  Test that your values are non-nil instead.  (e.g. `if let...`)

Comment: *unexpected found nil* is the #1 error in Swift. Please read the chapter about optionals in the Language Guide and [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Thanks Vadian currently reading this

Comment: Likely problems include either (a) failure to hook up the outlet correctly; (b) instantiating the view controller incorrectly; or (c) `imageName` is an optional that was never set. I'd suggest you expand the `self` section in the variables panel in the lower left of your first screen snapshot and see which of these is `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `userName.text` or `userPassword.text` doesn't have a value. This error can occur due to an unlinked outlet.

If your outlets are linked properly try this:

```
guard let userName = userName.text, let userMail = userMail.text, let userPassword = userPassword.text else {
    return
} 
Alamofire.request(.POST, urlRequest, parameters: ["X-API-KEY": API_GENERAL_KEY,"username":userName,"email": userMai,"password":userPassword,"profile_photo": self.imageName])
```

You will be able to catch the empty values without crashes.

*Let me know if it fixes your problem*

Comment: This fixed one of the crashes but I'm getting the THREAD 1: BAD_EXC_INSTRUCTION error in this field     if userName.text == "" || userMail.text == "" || userPassword.text == "" || self.imageName == ""

Comment: @NathanTrojanaudioBridge if you are using my guard statement, then check userName.isEmpty, userMail.isEmpty and userPassword.isEmpty

Comment: @NathanTrojanaudioBridge if it is in another point of the code you have to write again my guard before checking the empy string. Anyway check if the outlets are set

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the help guys, Marco's answer was the one that I used that fixed all the errors.

```
guard let userName = userName.text, let userMail = userMail.text, let userPassword = userPassword.text else {
return
} 
Alamofire.request(.POST, urlRequest, parameters: ["X-API-KEY": API_GENERAL_KEY,"username":userName,"email": userMai,"password":userPassword,"profile_photo": self.imageName])
```

Comment: If you want, mark my answer as right, I would appreciate it and then you can delete this answer, thank you

Comment: As an aside, that prevents the crash, but doesn't really tell you which was `nil`, nor why. Have you figured that out? Simply silently preventing the crash doesn't seem like that's enough...